# Custom module to show and store the current user's email address in the database

Tags: 8, blocks

I'm currently learning myself Drupal module development. I finished a tutorial for showing "Hello World!" in a block. And now I'm trying to show the logged in user's email and make a button to save it in the database. But I have no idea on how to start coding this.

I'm trying to show the logged in user's email. I'm using something like this and make it clickable with a mailto;

As for the purpose of the block, it's the exercise I'm making. The block needs to show the logged in users email with a mailto function on it and a button that adds the email to a newly made database. I suppose this is just for the purpose of adding data to the database.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\email_module\Plugin\Block\EmailBlock.
 */
namespace Drupal\email_module\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "EmailBlock",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Email Block")
 * )
*/
class EmailBlock extends BlockBase 
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
    public function build() {
        global $user;
        return array(
        '#markup' => $this->t('!email' => theme('email', array('account' => $user))),
    );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions to help me set this up?

Comment: It's not clear the purpose of that block, since the user email is already in the users database.

Comment: Made an edit to the post.

Comment: As side note, you don't use `$this->t()` in that way; there isn't anything translators can change in that output. If the call would be `$this->t('!email !username')`, translators could at least invert the order. Pus, there isn't any email theme, in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Examples module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples). It contains well documented examples of many Drupal development techniques.

In your case the DBTNG (Database: The Next Generation) example will show how to get input from a form and save to the database.

To get the email of the current user depends on the version of Drupal you are using.

Under Drupal 7 there's a $user gloabl variable containing the logged in user object. So $user->mail will return the email address.

Under Drupal 8, you can use the Drupal::currentUser method to get the user object. Drupal::currentUser()->mail should return the email address.

On a form, you can set the defaultValue of form field to the email address and it will prepopulate your field.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since the code is using PHP namespace, and specific classes, the code cannot be for Drupal 7.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. My reply was written before I saw the edits to the original post, which didn't mention it being in a block.

Comment: The Examples module also includes Block examples. I don't recall if there's one of a Form in a Block. I also came across this tutorial on D8 Blocks and Forms which might be helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-drupal-8-module-blocks-forms/

Comment: @JamesShields I am developing for Drupal 8 though, might have gotten the code markup mixed up. Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\email_module\Plugin\Block\Drupal' not found. I'm working in the file EmailBlock.php in the module directory.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for showing the email was this in the Block file.

```
<?php

class HelloBlock extends BlockBase 
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
    public function build() {
        $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $email = $user->get('mail')->value;
        return array(
        '#markup' => $this->t($email),
    );
    }
}
```